# Change form item editor type dynamically in smartGwt

Tags: forms, attributes, smartgwt

I have a smartGwt DynamicForm with a FormItem

```
FormItem item = createTextItem();           
form.setFields(item);
```

After creating the and setting fields, I need to dynamically set an editor type for the item. I have to do it dynamically based on some conditions.

I'm calling `item.setEditorType(new PasswordItem());`
just after I call `form.editRecord(record);` so that the new editor type should appear. But it is not working.
Tried calling `item.redraw()` and  is not working.

My goal is to set the editor type dynamically based on the record that is edited.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with Custom Data Binding ([see page 23](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/SmartGWT_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf) for more details). What you tried won't work, [AFAIK](http://forums.smartclient.com/forum/smart-gwt-technical-q-a/238544-how-to-properly-use-setfiltereditorproperties-new-minidaterangeitem-for-datetime), because the `ListGridField` has already been created with the initial custom editor, and it can't be changed dynamically with `setEditorCustomizer`.

Take a look at this sample (based on [this](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#update_grid_form_category) showcase demo), which does what you want to do to the password field when it is being edited in the DynamicForm, and after the changes have been saved (please pay attention to the comments, as without some of these settings it won't work as expected):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {  

    final DataSource dataSource = ItemSupplyLocalDS.getInstance();  

    final DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();  
    form.setIsGroup(true);   
    form.setNumCols(4);  
    form.setDataSource(dataSource);
    // very important for not having to set all fields all over again
    // when the target field is customized
    form.setUseAllDataSourceFields(true); 

    final ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();  
    listGrid.setWidth100();  
    listGrid.setHeight(200);  
    listGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);  
    listGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);  

    IButton editButton = new IButton("Edit");  
    editButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 
            form.editRecord(listGrid.getSelectedRecord()); 
            // when the button is clicked, the password field is rendered with 
            // a plain text item editor, for easy verification of values entered
            FormItem passwordField = new FormItem("passwordFieldName");
            passwordField.setEditorProperties(new TextItem());              
            form.setFields(passwordField);  
            form.markForRedraw();
        }  
    });  

    IButton saveButton = new IButton("Save");  
    saveButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {  
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {  
            form.saveData(); 
            // when the button is clicked, the password field is rendered with 
            // a password editor, for added privacy/security
            FormItem passwordField = new FormItem("passwordFieldName");
            passwordField.setEditorProperties(new PasswordItem());              
            form.setFields(passwordField);  
            form.markForRedraw();
        }  
    });  

    VLayout layout = new VLayout(15);  
    layout.setWidth100();
    layout.setHeight100();
    layout.addMember(listGrid);  
    layout.addMember(editButton); 
    layout.addMember(form);  
    layout.addMember(saveButton);  
    layout.draw();  
}
```

Comment: Now it works.  
SmartGwt is not rendering any changes made to the FormItem once it is set to a Form. But it worked when I made changes to the FormItem and again I set the formItem using `form.setFields(passwordField);` .
Thank you.